# How to remove fields on Django ModelForm?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, modelform

I would like to build a form with dynamically fields depends on needs and i have tried this code but doesn't work, the model form show all fields.

forms.py:

```
class CustomModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

  class Meta:
    model = app_models.CustomModel
    fields = '__all__'


  def __init__(self, excluded_fields=None, *args, **kwargs):

    super(CustomModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    for meta_field in self.fields:
      if meta_field in excluded_fields:

        # None of this instructions works
        -> del self.fields[meta_field]
        -> self.fields.pop(meta_field)
        -> self.fields.remove(meta_field)
```

Anybody could help me ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: the very same code works for me(apart from `self.fields.remove()`). Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the list of excluded_fields came from model._meta.get_fields(), not is a list of strings, and the if condition didnt matched well because self.fields is a python ordereddict.

This code solve the problem:

```
class CustomModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

  class Meta:
    model = app_models.CustomModel
    fields = '__all__'


 def __init__(self, excluded_fields=None, *args, **kwargs):

   super(CustomModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

   show_fields = []
   for field in excluded_fields:
     show_fields.append(field.name)

   for meta_field in list(self.fields):
     if meta_field not in show_fields:
       del self.fields[meta_field]
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, could you use the `modelform_factory`?

```
from django.forms import modelform_factory

CustomModelForm = modelform_factory(MyModel, exclude=('field_1', 'field_2'))
```

That way you could determine the exclude fields before creating the form, and just pass them into the factory, no need to override the constructor then.

Comment: But I need to be able to specify a specific form in the call to ModelForm_factory, because each one has its own characteristics and a different init and pass parameters in the init method. `form = modelform_factory(model = entry_model, form = entry_form, exclude = excluded_fields)`. How could i do that ?